# how can I count the occurences of strings with letter a?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to count how many names in my table have at least one letter 'a' or 'A' and how many of them have at least one letter 'e' or 'E'

effectively my question is how to do something along these lines:

```
SELECT count(lower(nazwisko) like '%a%') as "Ile nazwisk z A", count(lower(nazwisko) like '%e%') as "Ile nazwisk z E"
FROM pracownicy
```

as this code returns

```
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

"nazwisko" is a string column. I want to do that in a single query preferably without subqueries (if possible) for learning purpouses

Im using oracle sql developer

for reference let me include the table I am working on and expected output
[image: table view]

[image: expected output]

Comment: Use `case` _expressions_ to do _conditional aggregation_.

Comment: Note that count(expr) counts all non-null values.

Comment: Im sorry Im not sure I understand how to use case in this situation. The non-null values seem to me like not a problem (at least for now as the query does not work anyways)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN LOWER(nazwisko) LIKE '%a%' THEN 1 END) as "Ile nazwisk z A",
       COUNT(CASE WHEN LOWER(nazwisko) LIKE '%e%' THEN 1 END) as "Ile nazwisk z E"
FROM   pracownicy
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE pracownicy (nazwisko) AS
SELECT 'Alice' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Beryl' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Carol' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Debra' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Emily' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Fiona' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Glory' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Heidi' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Irene' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| Ile nazwisk z A | Ile nazwisk z E |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | 6 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/JnbWeq4A)

Answer (score 1):

How about `regexp_count` with case-insensitive search?

```
SQL> with temp (col) as
  2    (select 'This is A statement with some LETters' from dual)
  3  select regexp_count(col, 'a', 1, 'i') cnt_a,
  4         regexp_count(col, 'e', 1, 'i') cnt_e
  5  from temp;

     CNT_A      CNT_E
---------- ----------
         2          5

SQL>
```

---

**[EDIT]** Ah, it appears I got you wrong; you aren't counting letters within a string, but within a column.

Yet another variant of conditional aggregation, this time with `instr` function (and borrowed sample data):

```
SQL> with pracownicy (nazwisko) AS
  2  (
  3  SELECT 'Alice' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 'Beryl' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  5  SELECT 'Carol' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  6  SELECT 'Debra' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  7  SELECT 'Emily' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  8  SELECT 'Fiona' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  9  SELECT 'Glory' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 10  SELECT 'Heidi' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 11  SELECT 'Irene' FROM DUAL
 12  )
 13  select sum(case when instr(lower(nazwisko), 'a') > 0 then 1 else 0 end) cnt_a,
 14         sum(case when instr(lower(nazwisko), 'e') > 0 then 1 else 0 end) cnt_e
 15  from pracownicy;

     CNT_A      CNT_E
---------- ----------
         4          6

SQL>
```

Comment: Can you get case-sensitive search too? Perhaps 's' as 4:th argument?

Comment: unless I did something wrong that seems to count the amount of occurances of letter 'a' or 'e' in each string, whereas I am looking for a count of how many strings in my column have at least 1 letter 'a' or 'e' respectively

Comment: Right; sorry, I got you wrong. I left the original code (in case you or someone else finds it useful) and added another piece of code. I know you got the answer, but ... now you have a few options to consider.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you consider a subquery, I believe this will do it.

```
SELECT 
SUM(CASE WHEN lower(nazwisko) LIKE '%a%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Ile nazwisk z A", 
SUM(CASE WHEN lower(nazwisko) LIKE '%e%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Ile nazwisk z E" 
FROM pracownicy;
```

Comment: that helps, yet I want the count for letter 'a' and one for letter 'e' to be in seperate columns